# Kill/cancel low-priority build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How can I setup Jenkins to automatically cancel/kill low-priority jobs once higher priority jobs are available to run?

Some background -- there's a feature request for this capability:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8405

In the absence of such a feature being implemented, how might I accomplish this?  Some ideas I have are trying to read a potentially-existent Jenkins file that contains the list of jobs in the build.  And, I could launch the low priority jobs with a wrapper that spawns a separate process that monitors this file and kills the low-priority processes whenever a high-priority job needs to run.

But the above is fairly involved, and so I'd like to avoid doing that.  I could use linux "nice", except that the memory requirements are high, so it's really better to kill the processes.

Answer (score 1):

One partial solution is to use the Accelerated Build Now Plugin, which lets you cancel low priority jobs when you click the button.  That being said, an automatic version would be better.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could create a supervisor job that runs periodically and checks if high priority jobs are in the queue and aborts low priority jobs if needed.

Naturally you need to make sure that the supervisor job itself never gets stuck in the queue. One way to accomplish this would be to create a dedicated dummy slave for the supervisor job.